# How do I subtract 1 from each number in a list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've been using pandas to analyse football results and the betting odds from betfair. The 'back Odds' column displays the decimal odds of 3.5, 3.6 etc. I want to convert them to take 1 from each value, so it would show 2.5, 2.6 etc.

I created a new column called one, with 1,1,1, etc, then tried subtracting it from the Back Odds column.

```
df['Profit_Less-Stake'] = df['Back Odds'] - df['One']
```

I know this is wrong, but can't figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

`df['Profit_Less-Stake'] = df['Back Odds'] - 1` will do the trick. Pandas is really good at applying mathematical operations to columns. Can do `*2`, `/ 35`, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numeric data, simply:

```
df['Profit_Less-Stake'] = df['Back Odds'] - 1
```

Else:

```
df['Profit_Less-Stake'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Back Odds'], errors='coerce') - 1
```